# What Will Happen to the Embedded Web Browser Control in Visual Studio with Windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

Now that Windows 10 is beginning to roll out, what does this mean for the Web Browser control in visual studio? I'm pretty sure it is just a wrapper for Internet Explorer, so does this mean it will crash on Windows 10? Unless the new Edge browser will somehow automatically work with it.

For example:

I publish my application in Visual Studio which uses the Web Browser control. I distribute it to someone who is running Windows 10. What would happen?

Comment: Windows 10 includes IE, it just isn't the default browser any more.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Whats the WebBrowser control available in windows 10 Visual studio 2015 .Net framework latest version .Is it same as the old IE control or any improvements? especially suopport for html 5 content rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still uses Internet Explorer on Windows 10.

The other document modes (up to and including IE11) are available as well. I suspect that EdgeHTML will not be available, since it's in a different browser.

Comment: Whats the WebBrowser control available in windows 10 Visual studio 2015 .Net framework latest version .Is it same as the old IE control or any improvements? especially suopport for html 5 content rendering?

Comment: I had a totally different experience. Using Windows 10 anything to do with feature emulation failed, some basic DOM manipulation failed (could not set value of a password input type, for example), layout failed. Has to revert back to Windows8.1 (where same code worked without issue on same hardware). I assume it was using the Edge browser, but had to revert before I could fully investigate. Caveat Emptor.